# Keras Maxpooling2d layer gives ValueError

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to replicate VGG16 model in keras, the following is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(3,224,224)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))) ###This line gives error
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))
```

The maxpooling2d layer gives an error at the line which is commented

The error says:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'MaxPool_7' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,112,128].
```

What might be the reason behind this? How to solve this?

Edit:
A more detailed error log:

> ---
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        12 model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
>        13 
>   ---> 14 model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
>        15 
>        16 model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.pyc in add(self,
>   layer)
>       306                  output_shapes=[self.outputs[0]._keras_shape])
>       307         else:
>   --> 308             output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
>       309             if type(output_tensor) is list:
>       310                 raise Exception('All layers in a Sequential model '
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in
>   **call**(self, x, mask)
>       512         if inbound_layers:
>       513             # this will call layer.build() if necessary
>   --> 514             self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
>       515             input_added = True
>       516
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in
>   add_inbound_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
>       570         # creating the node automatically updates self.inbound_nodes
>       571         # as well as outbound_nodes on inbound layers.
>   --> 572         Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
>       573 
>       574     def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in
>   create_node(cls, outbound_layer, inbound_layers, node_indices,
>   tensor_indices)
>       147 
>       148         if len(input_tensors) == 1:
>   --> 149             output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
>       150             output_masks = to_list(outbound_layer.compute_mask(input_tensors[0], input_masks[0]))
>       151             # TODO: try to auto-infer shape if exception is raised by get_output_shape_for
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/pooling.pyc in
>   call(self, x, mask)
>       160                                         strides=self.strides,
>       161                                         border_mode=self.border_mode,
>   --> 162                                         dim_ordering=self.dim_ordering)
>       163         return output
>       164
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/pooling.pyc in
>   _pooling_function(self, inputs, pool_size, strides, border_mode, dim_ordering)
>       210                           border_mode, dim_ordering):
>       211         output = K.pool2d(inputs, pool_size, strides,
>   --> 212                           border_mode, dim_ordering, pool_mode='max')
>       213         return output
>       214
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc
>   in pool2d(x, pool_size, strides, border_mode, dim_ordering, pool_mode)
>   1699     1700     if pool_mode == 'max':
>   -> 1701         x = tf.nn.max_pool(x, pool_size, strides, padding=padding)    1702     elif pool_mode == 'avg':    1703
>   x = tf.nn.avg_pool(x, pool_size, strides, padding=padding)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.pyc
>   in max_pool(value, ksize, strides, padding, data_format, name)    1391
>   padding=padding,    1392
>   data_format=data_format,
>   -> 1393                                 name=name)    1394     1395
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.pyc
>   in _max_pool(input, ksize, strides, padding, data_format, name)
>   1593   result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("MaxPool", input=input,
>   ksize=ksize,    1594                                 strides=strides,
>   padding=padding,
>   -> 1595                                 data_format=data_format, name=name)    1596   return result    1597
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.pyc
>   in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
>       747           op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
>       748                            input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
>   --> 749                            op_def=op_def)
>       750           outputs = op.outputs
>       751           return _Restructure(ops.convert_n_to_tensor(outputs),
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc
>   in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs,
>   op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)    2388
>   original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)    2389     if
>   compute_shapes:
>   -> 2390       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)    2391     self._add_op(ret)    2392
>   self._record_op_seen_by_control_dependencies(ret)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc
>   in set_shapes_for_outputs(op)    1783       raise RuntimeError("No
>   shape function registered for standard op: %s"    1784
>   % op.type)
>   -> 1785   shapes = shape_func(op)    1786   if shapes is None:    1787     raise RuntimeError(
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.pyc
>   in call_cpp_shape_fn(op, input_tensors_needed, debug_python_shape_fn)
>       594                                                              status)
>       595   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as err:
>   --> 596     raise ValueError(err.message)
>       597 
>       598   # Convert TensorShapeProto values in output_shapes.
>
> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for
>   'MaxPool_7' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,112,128].

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Quoting an answer mentioned in [github](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3945), you need to specify the dimension ordering:

Keras is a wrapper over Theano or Tensorflow libraries. Keras uses the setting variable `image_dim_ordering` to decide if the input layer is Theano or Tensorflow format. This setting can be specified in 2 ways -

1. specify `'tf'` or `'th'` in `~/.keras/keras.json` like so -  `image_dim_ordering: 'th'`. Note: this is a [**json file**](https://keras.io/backend/#kerasjson-details).
2. or specify the `image_dim_ordering` in your model like so: `model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th"))`

**Update: Apr 2020** Keras 2.2.5 [link](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#maxpooling2d) seems to have an updated API where `dim_ordering` is changed to `data_format` so:

`keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format='channels_first')` to get NCHW or use `channels_last` to get NHWC

**Appendix:** `image_dim_ordering` in `'th'` mode the channels dimension (the depth) is at index 1 (e.g. 3, 256, 256). In `'tf'` mode is it at index 3 (e.g. 256, 256, 3). Quoting @naoko from comments.

Comment: @PranayMathur did not notice that!

Comment: Note: `dim_ordering`, In `'th'` mode, the channels dimension (the depth) is at index 1, in `'tf'` mode is it at index 3. 
For tensorflow 0.10 would use "tf" (default) and 0.11 would use "th". You can set this behavior in `~/.keras/keras.json`

Comment: @SrikarAppalaraju In you appendix, wouldn't that be Index 0 and Index 2 instead of 1 and 3?

Comment: TF2: Keyword argument not understood: 'dim_ordering'

Comment: is this answer valid for keras `2.2.5` ? cuz `MaxPooling2D` does not seem to have `dim_ordering` argument! `keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)`

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, I solved it by changing my padding: 'valid' to padding:'SAME': I guess its enough to add a parameter padding:' same'

```
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works. But you can also do the following:

```
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='block1_pool', data_format='channels_last')
```

Keras assumes input to be `(width, height, channels)` for TensorFlow backend and `(channel, width, height)` for Theano backend. Since your `input_shape=(3,224,224)`, specifying `data_format='channels_last'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the input shape as (3,x,y) should change it to input_shape=x,y,3

Comment: please expand your answer, i'm getting error like : `ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_2/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,20,1,32], [3,3,32,32].
`

Answer (score 1):

For keras with TensorFlow try following:

```
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, channel)))
```

Answer (score 0):

i also encountered the same problem while loading a per-trained **VGG** model. so i just took the transpose of the test images. the actual command is given below:

`kerasImage = kerasImage.transpose(1,2,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `dim_ordering` solved error for me:

```
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th"))
```