# Optimizing the Architecture of a CNN Using Keras in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, spectrogram

I am trying to increase my validation accuracy of my CNN from 76% (currently) to over 90%. I am going to show all of the information about my CNN's performance and configuration below.

In essence, I want my CNN to distinguish between two classes of mel-spectrograms:

**Class # 1** 
[image: class # 1]
**Class # 2**
[image]
**Here is the graph of accuracy vs epoch:**

[image]

**Here is the graph of loss vs. epoch**

[image]

Finally, here is the model architecture configuration

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=(3, 640, 480)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', dim_ordering="th"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

Here are my calls to model.compile() and model.fit()

```
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
print("Compiled model")

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
      batch_size=8,
      epochs=50,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

*How can I change my CNN configuration to increase the validation accuracy score?*

Things I have tried:

1. Decrease the learning rate to prevent sporadic fluctuations in the accuracy.
2. Decrease the batch_size from 64 down to 8.
3. Increase the number of epochs to 50(However not sure if this is enough).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE #1**
I increase the number of epochs to 200, and after letting the program run overnight I got a validated accuracy score of around 76.31%

I am posting a picture of accuracy vs. epoch and loss vs. epoch below

[image]

[image]

What else specifically about my model architecture can I change to get better accuracy?

Comment: how many samples are you using for training and for validation? Sometimes it's better to have a good initialization for your model. If you have enough data for training a deeper model you should try to finetune this model: [music-auto_tagging](https://github.com/keunwoochoi/music-auto_tagging-keras)

Comment: I am training on 993 images and am testing on like 243 images

Comment: @Eric How exactly would I use the music_tagging CNN, since isn't that trained on the million song dataset(thus for a different purpose entirely)?

Comment: You just have to change the output layer, and later set the layers that you don't want to train as non-trainable. If you don't know how to do it i will answer your question with some code ;)

Comment: I have some code that maybe can help you. [music genre recognition](https://github.com/ericpresas/music-genre-CNN)

Comment: What exactly is the dim ordering? Thanks!

Comment: @Eric if possible, could you post the tensorflow code in the MusicTaggerCNN as Keras code(as an answer)? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: dim ordering is how the dimensions of the image are ordered, you can see that Theano and Tensorflow use different image ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to get music_tagger_cnn.py and put it in the project path. After that you can build your model:

```
from music_tagger_cnn import *
input_tensor = Input(shape=(1, 18, 119))
model =MusicTaggerCNN(input_tensor=input_tensor, include_top=False, weights='msd')
```

You can change the input tensor by the dimension you want...
I usually use Theano dim ordering but Tensorflow as backend, so that's why:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

Using Theano dim ordering you hav to take into account that the order of the sample's dimensions have to be changed

```
X_train = X_train.transpose(0, 3, 2, 1)
X_val = X_val.transpose(0, 3, 2, 1)
```

After that you have to freeze these layers that you don't want to be updated

```
for layer in model.layers: 
     layer.trainable = False
```

Now you can set your own output, for example:

```
last_layer = model.get_layer('pool3').output
out = Flatten()(last_layer)
out = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc2')(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)
out = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax', name='fc3')(out)
model = Model(input=model.input, output=out)
```

After that you have to be able to train it just doing:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0, decay=0.002, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, labels_train,
                          validation_data=(X_val, labels_val), nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5)
```

Note that labels should be in one-hot encoding

I hope it will help!!

Update: Posting code so I can get help debugging these lines and prevent a crash.

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(3, 640, 480))
model = MusicTaggerCNN(input_tensor=input_tensor, include_top=False, weights='msd')

for layer in model.layers: 
     layer.trainable = False


last_layer = model.get_layer('pool3').output
out = Flatten()(last_layer)
out = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc2')(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)
out = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax', name='fc3')(out)
model = Model(input=model.input, output=out)

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0, decay=0.002, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, labels_train,
                          validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5)
```

EDIT # 2

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''MusicTaggerCNN model for Keras.

# Reference:

- [Automatic tagging using deep convolutional neural networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00298)
- [Music-auto_tagging-keras](https://github.com/keunwoochoi/music-auto_tagging-keras)

'''
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import ELU
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

TH_WEIGHTS_PATH = 'https://github.com/keunwoochoi/music-auto_tagging-keras/blob/master/data/music_tagger_cnn_weights_theano.h5'
TF_WEIGHTS_PATH = 'https://github.com/keunwoochoi/music-auto_tagging-keras/blob/master/data/music_tagger_cnn_weights_tensorflow.h5'


def MusicTaggerCNN(weights='msd', input_tensor=None,
                   include_top=True):
    '''Instantiate the MusicTaggerCNN architecture,
    optionally loading weights pre-trained
    on Million Song Dataset. Note that when using TensorFlow,
    for best performance you should set
    `image_dim_ordering="tf"` in your Keras config
    at ~/.keras/keras.json.

    The model and the weights are compatible with both
    TensorFlow and Theano. The dimension ordering
    convention used by the model is the one
    specified in your Keras config file.

    For preparing mel-spectrogram input, see
    `audio_conv_utils.py` in [applications](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/keras/applications).
    You will need to install [Librosa](http://librosa.github.io/librosa/)
    to use it.

    # Arguments
        weights: one of `None` (random initialization)
            or "msd" (pre-training on ImageNet).
        input_tensor: optional Keras tensor (i.e. output of `layers.Input()`)
            to use as image input for the model.
        include_top: whether to include the 1 fully-connected
            layer (output layer) at the top of the network.
            If False, the network outputs 256-dim features.


    # Returns
        A Keras model instance.
    '''
    if weights not in {'msd', None}:
        raise ValueError('The `weights` argument should be either '
                         '`None` (random initialization) or `msd` '
                         '(pre-training on Million Song Dataset).')

    # Determine proper input shape
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        input_shape = (3, 640, 480)
    else:
        input_shape = (3, 640, 480)

    if input_tensor is None:
        melgram_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    else:
        if not K.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
            melgram_input = Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
        else:
            melgram_input = input_tensor

    # Determine input axis
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        channel_axis = 1
        freq_axis = 2
        time_axis = 3
    else:
        channel_axis = 3
        freq_axis = 1
        time_axis = 2

    # Input block
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=freq_axis, name='bn_0_freq')(melgram_input)

    # Conv block 1
    x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', name='conv1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis, mode=0, name='bn1')(x)
    x = ELU()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 4), name='pool1')(x)

    # Conv block 2
    x = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', name='conv2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis, mode=0, name='bn2')(x)
    x = ELU()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 4), name='pool2')(x)

    # Conv block 3
    x = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', name='conv3')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis, mode=0, name='bn3')(x)
    x = ELU()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 4), name='pool3')(x)



    # Output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    if include_top:
        x = Dense(50, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(x)

    # Create model
    model = Model(melgram_input, x)
    if weights is None:
        return model
    else:
        # Load input
        if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'tf':
            raise RuntimeError("Please set image_dim_ordering == 'th'."
                               "You can set it at ~/.keras/keras.json")
        model.load_weights('data/music_tagger_cnn_weights_%s.h5' % K._BACKEND,
                           by_name=True)
        return model
```

EDIT #3

I tried the keras example for using the MusicTaggerCRNN as a feature extractor of the melgrams. Then i trained a simple NN with 2 Dense layers and a binary output. The samples taken in my example don't apply in your case but it's also a binary classifier
I used `keras==1.2.2` and `tensorflow-gpu==1.0.0` and works for me.

Here's the code:

```
from keras.applications.music_tagger_crnn import MusicTaggerCRNN
from keras.applications.music_tagger_crnn import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import SGD


model = MusicTaggerCRNN(weights='msd', include_top=False)
#Samples simulation
audio_paths_train = ['data/genres/blues/blues.00000.au','data/genres/classical/classical.00000.au','data/genres/classical/classical.00002.au', 'data/genres/blues/blues.00003.au']
audio_paths_test = ['data/genres/blues/blues.00001.au', 'data/genres/classical/classical.00001.au', 'data/genres/blues/blues.00002.au', 'data/genres/classical/classical.00003.au']
labels_train = [0,1,1,0]
labels_test = [0, 1, 0, 1]
melgrams_train = [preprocess_input(audio_path) for audio_path in audio_paths_train]
melgrams_test = [preprocess_input(audio_path) for audio_path in audio_paths_test]
feats_train = [model.predict(np.expand_dims(melgram, axis=0)) for melgram in melgrams_train]
feats_test = [model.predict(np.expand_dims(melgram, axis=0)) for melgram in melgrams_test]
feats_train = np.array(feats_train)
feats_test = np.array(feats_test)

_input = Input(shape=(1,32))
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(_input)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc6')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu', name='fc7')(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='fc8')(x)
class_model = Model(_input, x)

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0, decay=0.02, nesterov=True)
class_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = class_model.fit(feats_train, labels_train, validation_data=(feats_test, labels_test), nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5, class_weight='auto')
print(history.history['acc'])

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = class_model.evaluate(feats_test, labels_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1] * 100))
```

Comment: After running, I get this error    `raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'pool2/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,160,128].` .

Comment: Show me the size of the train set `X_train`. It should be in a numpy array

Comment: Printing X_train.shape yields dimensions of (993, 3, 640, 480)

Comment: This means that there are 993 images each with rgb with dimension 640 by 480 pixels

Comment: Okay, you should change your input tensor to your dimensions `(3, 640, 480)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815518/keras-maxpooling2d-layer-gives-valueerror

Comment: How do I reshape the input tensor

Comment: How do I specify the first layer input type if I am only retraining the last few layers?

Comment: I assume the sudo-code should be like this `model.getFirstLayer(dim_ordering="th")` How can I get the first layer in keras and change the input type @Eric

Comment: in second line of code in my answer the input tensor is called. so just change the second line for: `input_tensor = Input(shape=(3, 640, 480))`

Comment: i think your code should work, are you getting the same error?

Comment: Yes, however it should be noted that I didn't explicitly change the dim_ordering = "th" (I didn't know how/where to put it)

Comment: here you can change it: `~/.keras/keras.json`. Anyways putting `from keras import backend as K`
`K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')` in your code should work

Comment: After changing the dim_ordering, the old error went away, but was replaced with an OS error: **File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 78, in h5py.h5f.open (/private/var/folders/my/m6ynh3bn6tq06h7xr3js0z7r0000gn/T/pip-gkjbrkhs-build/h5py/h5f.c:2117)
OSError: Unable to open file (Unable to open file: name = 'data/music_tagger_cnn_weights_tensorflow.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'no such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)**

Comment: Okay, that was the problem. You have to delete the h5 file because this file have the weights for 'tf' din ordering, then execute again.

Comment: This github link where I downloaded the code https://github.com/ericpresas/music-genre-CNN doesn't have an h5 file

Comment: in music_tagger_cnn.py when you first execute the model, an h5 file will be downloaded to a data folder in the same path. You have check if the h5 file is downloaded.

Comment: i can provide you the h5 file if you want ;) https://github.com/keunwoochoi/music-auto_tagging-keras/blob/master/data/music_tagger_cnn_weights_tensorflow.h5. Download this file and create a directory in your path called `data`, then put the h5 file there

Comment: My program is crashing before the h5 file is created, could you upload the h5 file to github?

Comment: https://github.com/keunwoochoi/music-auto_tagging-keras/blob/master/data/music_tagger_cnn_weights_tensorflow.h5

Comment: I added the file in the data/ directory, after running I get this error **ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 640 and 1366 for 'Assign' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [640], [1366].**

Comment: change in music_tagger_cnn,py the input shape for yours. I think it will solve it

Comment: I changed it, still no luck :(, I will post the code in the music_tagger_cnn.py in the question as an edit(to the bottom of the file) I just changed it here:     `if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        input_shape = (3, 640, 480)
    else:
        input_shape = (3, 640, 480)`

Comment: I just tested it with gray-scale images as you can see. Maybe it doesn't work for rgb images. Check if in gray-scale images is working

Comment: What steps can I take to make it work for rgb images(if it is possible)

Comment: let me check it later and i will tell you!! Sorry ;) But keep it trying

Comment: Sure, anytime convenient for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155351/discussion-between-eric-and-sreehari-r).

Answer (score 0):

1. Dropout:
   It turns out that simple Dropout is not effective with CNNs. Try changing the first Dropout layer to SpatialDropout2D. The second Dropout is just for a standard Dense layer, so that is the right kind of Dropout.
   CNN networks create a series of overlapping pyramids. Standard Dropout just turns some of those pyramids into stumps. SpatialDropout complete zeroes out some of the pyramids, which is a better mode of "forgetting".
2. Repeated structure:
   Use a few different copies of your Conv2D->Conv2D->SpatialDropout chain, making downsized images with more filters. All of the successful image-processing designs use multiple repeated blocks.
3. Your data:
   Spectrograms have two different measurements as the different dimensions of the "image". The normal design for image processing is to consider all of the neighbor pixels as equally contributing to one output feature. It may be that you want many pixels in one row to contribute to a feature map, but only one or two rows. So, maybe each pyramid needs a long&narrow base.

Answer (score 0):

you can do several preliminary modifications to your code and check result:

1. increase layers count
2. increase layers size
3. change learning_rate
4. change optimizer (usually Adam works better than SGD ,...)
5. shuffle your data(maybe your test data include some samples which are far from training samples
6. try adding batch normalization layers
7. also sometimes increasing MFCC features number helps(instead of 640, 480 try extracting more features